# JSON result is an stdObject but how to traverse it?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have my data in a variable which when output looks something like this

```
object(stdClass)#1 (20) { ["Link"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["Text"]=> string(30) "A.Ilkley Moor Medical Practice" ["Uri"]=> string(87) "http://v1.syndication.nhschoices.nhs.uk/organisations/gppractices/25599?apikey=LDVVTHBM" } ["Address"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (6) { ["Line1"]=> string(28) "Ilkley Moor Medical Practice" ["Line2"]=> string(17) "The Health Centre" ["Line3"]=> string(12) "Springs Lane" ["Line4"]=> string(6) "Ilkley" ["Line5"]=> string(0) "" ["Postcode"]=> string(7) "LS298TH" }
```

Question is how do I get to each individual element. I have tried converting the object to an array but is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $object)
{
  foreach ($object as $property=>$value)
   {
     echo $property." has the value ". $value;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem was I needed to to json_decode($data) on the variable.

Comment: Trying to assign the $value to variables doesn't work however:

Answer (score 0):

Why would this not work, i.e. not assign values to the variables :

```
foreach (json_decode($data) as $object)
{
  foreach ($object as $property=>$value)
   {
     echo $property." has the value ". $value;
     switch ($property) {
        case 'Text':            
            $practice_name = $value;
            break;
        case 'Uri':
            $Website = $value;          
            break;
        case 'Line1':
            $Address1 = $value;
            break;
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: The website value was causing an issue. Quite hard to spot without a debugger.